# Strange things inside Perl diamond operator

Tags: perl, diamond-operator

Please, can anyone help me with this:

```
perl -e 'print for <{a,b,c}{1,2,3}>'
```

I just don't understand how it works. And it works! Producing

```
a1a2a3b1b2b3c1c2c3
```

on output.

Does anyone know what is happening inside diamond operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's another way to represent [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)bing. Basically the curlies tell the `glob` operator to take each comma-separated element inside and combine across all possibilities.

A clearer way to see this is to comma-separate the individual outputs:

```
$ perl -e 'print join ",", <{a,b,c}{1,2,3}>;'
a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3
```

---

From [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) :

> If non-empty braces are the only wildcard characters used in the glob,
>   no filenames are matched, but potentially many strings are returned.
>   For example, this produces nine strings, one for each pairing of
>   fruits and colors:
>
> ```
> @many =  glob "{apple,tomato,cherry}={green,yellow,red}";
> ```

Comment: So this is about glob. Thanks for the clue!